# Use Font-Awesome with SDL Tridion

Tags: 2011, rtf

I'd like to use Font-Awesome (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome) in one of my projects but the CMS I'm using (SDL Tridion) is removing font-awesome characters like  from it's rich text fields. Characters like   aren't beiing removed.

Does anyone one how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like those characters are not UTF8, but why are you using characters, isn't he whole idea of Font Awesome to use the `<i>` tag with classes?

Comment: Because I want to use those characters in an input type=submit

Comment: I am guessing the RTF area is UTF 16 compatible, since it supports Japanese, etc.  If this is true and it supports the charset, you might need to edit the XSLT defined for the field in the Schema edit screen, and then in your publication target change UTF8 to UTF16.  However, it seems like an awful lot of work for 1 special character.  Is it really worth it?

Comment: UTF8 and UTF16 can represent the exact same characters.
As far as I can see (if I didn't get big/little endian confused), the character is UTF code F084, which is in the private use area. I do not know where it gets removed, but it should not be related to UTF8/16 (or 7/32 for that matter). Maybe the tidy call removes it?

Comment: No, the character is there - it's just not rendered as there is no font for it. :) To see there is a character copy the text into Notepad.

Answer (score 4):

Tridion 2011 and later releases use Tidy to process RTF fields content. You can configure the characters set to be used there.

Tidy configuration is located here: 
[TRIDION_HOME]\web\WebUI\Core\Controls\FormatArea\TcmXhtml\TcmXHTML.config

Tidy documentation can be found here:
http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html